# Пропадают данные переданные во вторую форму

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема: в первой форме я создаю вторую форму и передаю ей значения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перед этим я добавил в конструктор значения, в которые сохраняются данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее данные пропадают. Тут выдается ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через локальный отладчик я заметил, что данные пропадают после вызова ShowDialog(), либо просто Show(), по сути во время записи в numVertexFirst вектор оказывается пуст, и выводит ошибку. Указатель до этого момента я не переприсваиваю и данные во вторую форму более никакие не передаю, начальные также не изменяю. 
Из-за чего происходит потеря данных непонятно...

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте код в текст вопроса.

Comment: Не нужно здесь код в текст вопроса вставлять, никто его списывать не будет, единственное - темная цветовая гамма непривычна среди светлого, бьет по глазам, но это не повод минусовать, но раз все минусуют - то и я, третий минус - мой, держитесь там!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так Вы и передавайте указатель. Вы передаете объект по значению, соответственно впоследствии, получая адрес объекта MST, Вы получаете адрес локальной копии. Передавайте значения по указателю: `drawMST(MST* object)`. Аналогично - для конструктора класса формы.

*P.S. Скриншоты с хай-лайтом кода, конечно, красиво, но вот код руками переписывать - не очень удобно.*

Comment: Помогло, странно только, что в самом конструкторе при пересылке объекта данные запоминались в ptrobj, то есть по отладчику, если смотреть, все 6 значений были, но не сохранялись окончательно. Спасибо.

Comment: @fearyt98, давайте объясню более подробно: Вы передаете в конструктор объект, при этом создается его копия (передаем по значению), здесь же Вы берете адрес этого объекта и присваиваете его ptrobj. На этом все. После выхода из конструктора - локальный объект (возможно, правильнее бы было назвать его _временным_) разрушается, и переменная ptrobj хранит адрес уже несуществуещего объекта.

Comment: Теперь все на своих местах, спасибо)